# How to hide/show UI Navigation Bar for certain UIViews

Tags: swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

Please see the storyboard below: 
[image]

I need to dynamically hide UINavigationBar for UITableViewController "Zero" and show it for UITableViewController "One" and "Two".

What is the best approach?

Comment: have you been able to check out one of the solutions?

Comment: Hide the navigationController in viewWillAppear. Don't forget to add show the same in other classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this..

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
}
```

you could use viewWillDisappear to set it to visible again

Comment: Thank you for such an elegant solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `hidden` property of the `UINavigationBar` when the views appear...

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.hidden = true
```

Just do this in the views where you want the nav bar hidden

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a method which hides the NavigationController very smooth after one second... I prefer this than just hiding it ;)

```
   var navigation: UINavigationController!

override func viewDidLoad() {
        navigation = navigationController!
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "animate", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }

    func animate(){
        hideController(self.navigation)
    }

    func hideController(navigationController: UINavigationController){
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {

            self.navigationController.alpha = 0.0

            }, completion: nil)
}


    override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        if self.navigationController!.respondsToSelector("interactivePopGestureRecognizer") {
            timer.invalidate()
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarHidden = false
        }
    }
```

I hope I could help you

you could also put the hide function into another class, so you don't need to retype it in the other views.

Edit:

I forgot to mention.. When you go one view back, you need to set you NavigationController back to visible... Therefore create another method for example the function `show` and set it's alpha to 1.0

```
    func show(navigationController: UINavigationController){
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {

            self.navigationController.alpha = 1.0

            }, completion: nil)
}
```